# Awkward bug in C program

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

```
Console* initConsole(Controller* ctrl){
    if (ctrl == NULL)
        return NULL;
    Console* c = (Console*)malloc(sizeof(Console));
    c->ctrl = ctrl;
    return c;
}
```

*expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token*

This error appears in one of my modules.For some functions the "{" wasn't on the same row as the header of the function so I pressed a backspace,saved and debuged.The module was clean but the error went to another module and I have no ideea of what's wrong.

Comment: Missing semicolon in included header?

Comment: It looks like one of `Console` or `Controller` is not a recognized type.  Otherwise, the code seems likely to be sensible.

Comment: On a side note, this: `Console* c = malloc(sizeof(*c))` is preferable to `Console* c = (Console*)malloc(sizeof(Console));`

Comment: Try writing a simple hello world program that includes the same headers that your module does and compile it one-off. Do you get the same thing? If so, it's in the headers (lets you quickly eliminate anything else prior to what you posted).

Comment: @MateiMarius: Because A) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc, and B) if you change the type of `c` then your call to malloc is wrong until you change the `sizeof` bit as well.  However, if you use `*c` then `sizeof` will always return the correct number of bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I most often get this if I forget to put a semi-colon after a forward declaration (possibly in an included header)